# Does $P(B|A) \neq P(B| A^c)$ prove dependence?

Tags: independence

Does P(B|A)!=P(B|!A) prove dependence?

!= means 'is not equal to'

!A means 'not A' or 'the complement of A'

Thanks.

Edit:  I believe I may have proved that inequality shows dependence.

Proof:

1)  Assume independence.

```
            P(AB)=P(A)P(B)

            P(B)=P(AB)/P(A)

            P(B)=P(B|A)

    2)  Repeat with !A

            P(A!B)=P(A)P(!B)

            P(B)=P(!AB)/P(!A)

            P(B)=P(B|!A)

    3)  Therefore

            P(B|A)=P(B|!A)
```

By contradiction, the events are dependent.

Comment: Are A and B the only two events that are possible?

Comment: @user1357015 Yes.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. If in fact A & B are independent, then $Pr(B) = Pr(B|A^c)$ and $Pr(B) = Pr(B|A)$? Why? Because,under independence, it doesn't matter what A is when calculating the probability of B conditioned on A (By the fact of independence!). Take a look at mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think one may proceed as follows:

Suppose A & B ARE independent. That means $P(A \& B) = P(A)P(B) \Rightarrow Pr(B|A) = Pr(B) $

Now from your equation, that would mean that $Pr(B|A) \neq Pr(B|A^c)$ which by independence of A and B would imply that:

$Pr(B) \neq Pr(B)$

since $Pr(B|A) = Pr(B)$ and $Pr(B|A^c) = Pr(B)$ (using th indepdence property).

Clearly that is false. That means A & B are dependent.

Comment: From A and B being independent, how can you say that $A^c$ and B are also independent?

Comment: @user1357015 thank you. our proofs are similar.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I asked if A & B are the only two possible so it seems to me you're either in A or in B? No?

Comment: @Guest: Not quite, your proof doesn't work because under independence I think that's what you expect? Don't forget to mark as answered if you agree :-).

Comment: I maybe wrong, but, if A and B are the only two possible sets, then B=$A^c$. Or is there another meaning that I don't understand?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Here's a proof of "If A & B are indepedent, then $A \& B^c$ are independent". https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100328144146AAKNKoS